# Numpy Array manipulation - Accessing element before a certain element

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
my_array = np.array([(np.datetime64('1970-01-01'),
                   np.array([np.zeros(12), np.zeros(12)], dtype='float64'),
                   np.array([np.zeros(12), np.zeros(12)], dtype='uint64'),
                   np.array([np.zeros(12), np.zeros(12)], dtype='uint64'),
                   np.array([np.empty(12, dtype='<M8[us]'),
                             np.empty(12, dtype='<M8[us]')]),
                   np.array([np.empty(12), np.empty(12)], dtype='object'),
                   np.array([np.empty(1, dtype='uint64'),
                             np.empty(1, dtype='uint64')]))],
                   dtype=[('index', 'datetime64[us]'), ('price', 'object'), ('quantity', 'object'),
                          ('id', 'object'), ('timestamp', 'object'), ('customer', 'object'),
                          ('action', 'object')])
```

1. I have a numpy recarray initialised as above. The array contains 12 elements for most of the fields except the field 'action' and field 'index'. I want to now filter this array by all elements where action = 2 and I want to retrieve the element in the array just before the action == 2 item.
2. Once I achieve the above i want to compare the difference between the two arrays, it would be deletion of an item from the basket. How do I achieve this in an efficient manner?

Comment: The whole format seems to be pretty confusing to be honest. The entire array has just 1 index, price is an array inside which there are two arrays (as opposed to a 2d array?) etc and action is empty

Comment: I tried to use recarrays so i can access elements by their name. Is there a better format you would suggest to store all of these elements that have various lengths? Action is initialised to empty but later filled with values

Comment: No the the recarray is alright, but simply the nature of your data is confusing. For example, as it is now, there is just one index, 0. If we access my_array[0]['action'] we get [[0],[0]]. Your question says you want to check "where action = 2". Do you want to check the 'values inside action'(here the values are 0 and 0)? Or do you want to check 'how many values are there in action'(here action has 2 values)?

Comment: No so this is 1 record of an array and actually this is just the initialisation. I add elements to this array later on in a loop. At the end of element addition now i want to do various things with this array.

Comment: Please include another element to the array, and show an output of one thing that you want to do with it (almost for sure you will figure out the rest once you know how to do one thing). It is hard to understand what you want to accomplish. Also, please answer Mercury's question: Do you want to check the 'values inside action'(here the values are 0 and 0)? Or do you want to check 'how many values are there in action'(here action has 2 values)?